# Python Selenium select all links in specific element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code which works fine gets and lists all of the links in the given URL however I'm struggling to make it work when I want to get links in a specific tag. I'm new to Python.

My code is:

```
chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
chromedriver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/usr/username")
links = chromedriver.find_elements("xpath", ".//a[@href]")

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Tag is:

```
<ol class="pagination__items">
</ol>
```

Comment: I also need to include **class="pagination__items"** in this selection too.

Comment: Like this? `//ol[@class="pagination__items"]//a[@href]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath:

```py
links = chromedriver.find_elements('xpath', '//ol[@class="pagination__items"]//a[@href]')
```